# Is it possible to log into home directory via the internet

Tags: 12.04, apache2

I've got a home fileserver running Ubuntu 12.04 server edition. I am curious if there is a web interface available that will allow users to log into their home directories to view or even download their files. The basic concept that I had in mind was to create a photo gallery that was viewable via the web, but I would like to prevent the entire world from viewing those photos.

I am capable of developing the web interface, I am just unsure if it is possible for Apache to log into local user accounts.

Answer (score 0):

There are several project to do that.

Check this one http://galleryproject.org/.

The packages to be installed with apt-get should name gallery2